# Is there a way to GLOBALLY set the DEFAULT keyserver for gpg on Debian?

Tags: gpg

I am not asking for per-request of a key, I know how to do that, but I want a chosen alternative gpg keyserver to be defaulted to, when no specific keyserver is specified in a request then-on-out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17):

At ubuntu a standard keyserver is set.

You can add the entry:

```
keyserver NAME_OF_KEYSERVER
```

in file `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`

Answer (score 4):

According to the doc, gpg has no global configuration file, it is strictly user-based and takes the config **only** from the `~/.gnupg` directory or from a directory specified by `--homedir` option on the command line.

As @sim noted, one solution is to alter the default skeleton file for creating the user's cfg file. On Debian, it is located here `/usr/share/gnupg/options.skel`

In the man page of `gpgconf` utility, there arises a second possibility:

```
--apply-defaults
          Update all configuration files with values taken from the global configuration file (usually ‘/etc/gnupg/gpgconf.conf’).
```

The keyserver option is supported, you can check with:

```
gpgconf --list-options gpg
```

So placing the dafault keyserver in the `/etc/gnupg/gpgconf.conf` and calling `gpgconf --apply-defaults` for the particular user could be used also.

Comment: And the line inside `gpgconf.conf` that would set `keyserver` to Ubuntu one for any user would be `* gpg keyserver [change] "hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `gpg` commands man page and how it behaves when there is no `$HOME/.gnugpg` directory present I'm not sure how this would work. When you have no `$HOME/.gnugpg` directory present, `gpg` will create one for you.

```
$ gpg --list-keys --fingerprint
gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
```

The only idea I can conceive of here would be to put your default key server in the file that's used to populate a user's directory when they run `gpg` for the first time, but this is only marginally going to give you what you want.

So in my analysis I do not see a way to do what you ask.